# Applying a function row-wise for a dataset

Tags: r

hope am able to explain clearly what I would like to do.

I have a matrix

```
  Z<-matrix(sample(1:40),ncol=4)

 colnames(Z)<-c("value","A","B","C")

 I would like to apply the following formula to each row in the dataset.


  Process = value - rowmean (A,B,C)
           ------------------------------------
           row-wise Standard deviation (A,B,C)
```

I thought of something like calculating everything separately like

Subsettting the data first

```
   onlyABC<-Z[,1:3]
```

Then apply the rowMeans to each row

```
     means<-apply(onlyABC,1,rowMeans)
```

And similarly compute standard deviation separately using

```
    deviate<-apply(onlyABC,1,SD)
```

And then I do not know now how to subtract the value column in matrix 'z' from 'means' and then divide by 'deviate'.

Is there a simpler approach to do this?

As an example applying the formula to the first row will give:

```
 row1  32-(19+35+4/3)
       --------------
        SD(19+35+4)
```

Similarly apply the formula to other rows as well and get a vector of size 10 in the end.

Comment: you did everything in the correct and probably fastest way (using `matrix` or `data.frame`). once you have `means` and `deviate` just do `(Z[,1]-means)/deviate`. such operation are vectorized in R. See Metrics's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ksd<-apply(Z[,-1],1,sd)
kmean<-rowMeans(Z[,-1])
 Z[,1]<-(Z[,1]-kmean)/ksd
> Z
            value  A  B  C
 [1,]  0.88181533 26  4 31
 [2,] -0.04364358 17 22  7
 [3,]  2.21200505 25 13 18
 [4,]  0.50951017  8 34 40
 [5,]  0.03866223 12  6 23
 [6,] -0.64018440 29 16 30
 [7,] -0.40927275 39 35  9
 [8,] -0.65103077 24  5  1
 [9,]  0.89658092 37 27  3
[10,]  0.26360896 11 10 28
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite an apply problem, as you want to exclude the first column of each row from the calculation.

The iterative way of doing this is to first create the output vector, and then substitute into it as follows:

```
tranZ <- vector('numeric', length = nrow(Z))
for (i in 1:nrow(Z)) {
    tranZ[i] <- (Z[i,1] - mean(Z[i,-1])) / sd(Z[i,-1])
}
```

If you have a large data-set, i suggest using the power of vectorisation -- try the following:

```
(Z[,1] - rowMeans(Z[,-1])) / apply(Z[, -1], 1, sd)
```

Or with `vapply`:

```
tranZ_v <- vapply(1:nrow(Z), function(X) (Z[X, 1] - mean(Z[X, -1])) / sd(Z[X, -1]),
                FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))
```

The key to using the `*apply` family in this case is controlling the application -- to do this i've iterated across `1:nrow(Z)` rather than the object itself: calling the object in the function.

---

**Benchmarking**

```
require(rbenchmark)

process <- function(x) {
    (x[["value"]] - mean(c(x[["A"]], x[["B"]], x[["C"]]))) / sd(c(x[["A"]], x[["B"]], x[["C"]]))
}          

p2 <- function(x) {
    (x[1] - mean(x[-1])) / sd(x[-1])
}

apply_fun <- function() apply(Z, 1, process)
apply_fun2 <- function() apply(Z, 1, p2)

apply_sd <- function() (Z[,1] - rowMeans(Z[,-1])) / apply(Z[, -1], 1, sd)

vapply_anon <- function() vapply(1:nrow(Z), FUN = function(X) (Z[X, 1] - mean(Z[X, -1])) / sd(Z[X, -1]),
                FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))


bb <- benchmark(apply_fun(), apply_fun2(), apply_sd(), vapply_anon(), 
          columns = c('test', 'elapsed', 'relative'), 
          replications = 100, 
          order = 'elapsed')
```

The vectorised approach, using apply for only the `sd` is fastest:

```
> bb
           test elapsed relative
3    apply_sd()   0.021    1.000
4 vapply_anon()   0.030    1.429
1   apply_fun()   0.033    1.571
2  apply_fun2()   0.034    1.619
```

Answer (score 2):

```
process <- function(x) {
    (x[["value"]] - mean(c(x[["A"]], x[["B"]], x[["C"]])) / sd(c(x[["A"]], x[["B"]], x[["C"]])))
}           

apply(Z, 1, process)
```

Comment: Works for this sample but mine is a large dataset.

Comment: @Paul if speed is a problem then you should have mentioned in the question. Now, why don't you take all the answers you've got and run a benchmark and compare the different timings? (you can use `microbenchmark`)

Comment: note, this function has an error and gives the wrong result. It is missing a paren: it should be `process <- function(x) {(x[["value"]] - mean(c(x[["A"]], x[["B"]], x[["C"]]))) / sd(c(x[["A"]], x[["B"]], x[["C"]]))}`